# Groovy Functional Programming: Round-Robin Filter

Tags: groovy, functional-programming

On my quest to learn (more) functional programming, I have a semi-contrived example that I'm able to write an adequate solution for imperatively, but a functional solution is confounding me.

Given a method which returns a `List` in round-robin fashion, I want to repeatedly call this method until the first element in the `List` passes some criteria. But I must avoid an infinite loop in case none of the elements meet the criteria.

Here is how I've solved the problem imperatively.

```
class RoundRobin {
    private final Random random = new Random()
    private final int size = random.nextInt(5) + 5
    private final List<Integer> list = (0..size).collect { random.nextInt(10) }

    List<Integer> list() {
        Collections.rotate(list, -1)
        return list.asImmutable()
    }
}

class RoundRobinFilter {
    static final RoundRobin RR = new RoundRobin()
    static void main(String... args) {
        println filterProcedural()
    }

    static List<Integer> filterProcedural() {
        int count = 0
        while (true) {
            List<Integer> candidate = RR.list()
            println candidate

            if (candidate.first() > 8) {
                return candidate
            }
            if (++count >= candidate.size()) {
                return []
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stylistically, I don't like the mutable index variable; I don't like the unconditional loop; and I don't like the branching return statements. In short, I'd like to write this in a functional programming style.

Here is my attempt.

```
static List<Integer> filterFunctional() {
    List<Integer> candidate = RR.list()
    candidate.findResult([]) {
        println candidate
        return candidate.first() > 8 ? candidate : {candidate = RR.list(); null}.call()
    }
}
```

This is shorter, but still includes a mutable variable, repeats the `list()` call twice, and has a ridiculous closure to produce a side effect and return `null`.

Please show me a functional way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. You could implement Iterator with class RoundRobin

then you could do like this to find result in a functional way:

```
RR.find{ it.first()>8 }
```

> Beware! The `RoundRobin.list` member could be initialized without any `9` so loop will be infinite.

Iterator implementation:

```
class RoundRobin implements Iterator<List<Integer>>{
    private final Random random = new Random()
    private final int size = random.nextInt(5) + 5
    private final List<Integer> list = (0..size).collect { random.nextInt(10) }

    List<Integer> list() {
        Collections.rotate(list, -1)
        return list.asImmutable()
    }
    //methods to support iterator
    List<Integer> next(){ list() }
    boolean hasNext(){ true }

}
```

---

2. limited iterations to prevent infinitive loop and no RoundRobin change required

```
List<Integer> filterFunctional(Closure c = {it.first()>8} ) {
    return (0..100).findResult{
        RR.list().with{ c(it) ? it : null }
    }
}
```

then it's possible to use it:

```
filterFunctional{ it.first()==7 }
```

or with default closure `{it.first()>8}`

```
filterFunctional()
```

Comment: The range `(0..100)` is just a guess though, unless I retrieve the list to determine its size before iterating.